# Argument of type 'typeof test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<{ children?: ReactNode; } & DispatchProp<any>>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';


interface types{

type:string;
status?:boolean;

}


export class Test extends React.Component<undefined,any> {

constructor(props:undefined){
    super(props);
}

private test(){}

render(){
    return(
      <h1 onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>
        test
      </h1>
    )
}

}

export default connect()(Test);
```

Error

> Argument of type 'typeof test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<{ children?: ReactNode; } & DispatchProp>'.
>   ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you need to connect this component to redux at all. You're not providing functions to connect the redux state or dispatch to the props of your component. You can actually just remove the `connect` call altogether. As for the error, it's because your props is set to `undefined` and doesn't implement any of the required properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overengineering your component; it doesn't need to `connect` to redux at all as it doesn't make use of either the state or dispatch. Also, the error itself refers to the fact that the type of `props` is `undefined` and so doesn't implement any of the required properties for connected components.

Here's the simplified component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Test extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    private test() {}

    render() {
        return(
            <h1 onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>
                test
            </h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ***Thank you very much for your answer***